# Is there anyway to let RubyMine choose first completion choice like Intellij Idea?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, intellij-idea, rubymine

Intellij Idea like this:(when I click `enter` the auto completion code will appear on the line)[image: Intellij Idea like this:]

RubyMine like this:
The idea does not auto choose the first one.So I need to click `down` button and choose the select one.[image: RubyMine like this]

So I want to know is there anyway to let RubyMine choose first completion choice like Intellij Idea?

Comment: Use the tab key and it will select the first one.

Comment: @engineersmnky Thank you very much .Tab key can really help to select the first one.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Autocompletion's behaviour in RubyMine has been changed since there were a lot of complains against it in previous versions (because it was choosing not always the desirable one option).

If you want to restore the old behaviour, type "Registry" in Search everywhere and look for **ide.completion.lookup.element.preselect.depends.on.context** and unselect it.
Note: To  **Search Everywhere** double press "Shift" key. Don't mistake this for searching inside preferences window.

Comment: Thank you! But when I searched "Registry" in RubyMine(version 7.1) there is only a Keymap.I searched "Registry" in Mac and did not find a file called "ide.completion.lookup.element.preselect.depends.on.context ".Could you tell me more steps of how to find it?

Comment: I suppose you were searching in Preferences , try doing it from the Search everywhere field:

https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/help/searching-everywhere.html

Comment: So nice! Android Studio does this perfectly and I was always so frustrated with RubyMine not doing so. Thanks @Olivia!

Comment: "Search everywhere" does not return any results in ruby mine 8.0.3, is there another way to change this? Some rubymine application file?

Comment: Note, that this will automatically choose the element when typing `space`, `dot` - or pretty much any non-symbol keypress. That renders it unusable and that is why it's disabled by default.

Comment: @LordZardeck Try Shift+Cmd+A to open the Actions menu, and you can open the Registry from there.

Answer (score 0):

There is now an option for this in the settings.

Go to `Settings > Editor > Code Completion` in the Ruby section and uncheck the checkbox `Preselect first completion element` :

[image]